# Programming Applet with servlet in Netbeans

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications, netbeans, japplet

I building web application program using Netbeans 7.4 by creating jApplet file that communicate with servlet by Serializable object. Servlet file will communicate with DB and send results to applet and also applet has to use the Serializable object to send and receive data from servlet. I actually created both servlet and `JApplet` files under the source folder directory. The error is I ma not getting any communication between `JApplet` and servlet, and keeps giving me "protocol doesn't support output". Here is my Applet code that connecting to servlet:

```
    myObject = new ExpertDataObject();

    ((ExpertDataObject) myObject).setSession("EnterUser");

    ((ExpertDataObject) myObject).setUser(userText.getText());
    ((ExpertDataObject) myObject).setPassword(passText.getText());
    URL currentPage = getCodeBase();
    System.out.println(currentPage);

    String urlSuffix = "Server";
    URL urlServlet = new URL(getCodeBase(), "Server");
    System.out.println(urlServlet);

    URLConnection con = urlServlet.openConnection();

    con.setUseCaches(false);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-java-serialized-object");

    myOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());

    myInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(con.getInputStream());

    myOutputStream.writeObject(myObject);

    myObject = (DataObject) myInputStream.readObject();
    if (myObject.getMessage().equals("success")) {
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

....

Can anyone help me showing the steps of creating jApplet communicating with servlet +mySQL as web application in Netbeans.

Thanks in advance

Arwa

Here is what I found in Server log
Feb 12, 2014 11:53:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Server] in context with path [/ExpertToolAppletServlet2] threw exception
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2325)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2794)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
    at Server.processRequest(Server.java:73)
    at Server.doGet(Server.java:177)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

And here is here is my servlet code under processRequest

```
   String contentType = "application/x-java-serialized-object";
   response.setContentType(contentType);
   InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
   ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
   myObject = (DataObject) in.readObject();
   String process= ((ExpertDataObject) myObject).getSession();
```

Comment: What is the output of `System.out.println(urlServlet);` ?

Comment: Hi peeskillet, thanks for reply, It is file:/Users/arwawali/Documents/NetBeansProjects/ExpertToolAppletServlet/build/web/WEB-INF/Server,  Server is my servlet class name, and I looked to the path, I did not find the class there, how we can get servlet class path on the server other than using  getCodeBase()?

Comment: The `file:/` protocol does not allow writing. Read further here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975743/getting-applets-outputstream-throws-an-exception-what-is-wrong

Comment: Thanks PeterMmm for reply, I have change urlServlet to  URL urlServlet = new URL("http://localhost:8080/ExpertToolAppletServlet2/Server"); Now I am getting this error:  Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8080/ExpertToolAppletServlet2

Comment: `500 - Internal Server Error` look into the server log for the cause.

Comment: Thanks PeterMmm, I edited the post, because I could not add the long reply here in Comment.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the server's 500 error message: As the docs for EOFException is saying: `This exception is mainly used by data input streams to signal end of stream.` you may try to catch the Exception:

```
   String contentType = "application/x-java-serialized-object";
   response.setContentType(contentType);
   InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
   ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);

   myObject = null;
   try {
        myObject = (DataObject) in.readObject();
   } catch (EOFException ignore) {
   }

   if (myObject!=null) { 
      String process= ((ExpertDataObject) myObject).getSession();
   }
```

Comment: I catched the exception, but I really do not know if there is any other way to read object from jApplet. Is that mean I have to run the code only from index.jsp file, or I can run it from source folder itself knowing that both jApplet and servlet in the same folder under web application project? Thank again for help.

Comment: Applets are running in the browser with Java plugin on client side.

Comment: Is this the right way to refer to jApplet in the source folder from index.jsp,  <applet code="http://localhost:8080/ExpertToolAppletServlet2/MainScreen" width="700" height="500"></applet>, (MainScreen is jApplet class) ?

Comment: No, `code` is the FQN of the JApplet class. Read further here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/html.html

Comment: Thanks so much PeterMmm. I will try your to catch the Exception